# I want jQuery to play a sound when an animation starts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements on my page that animate in and when they do I would like each of them to have their own sound. The animation is as follows, this includes the targetBeep sound.

```
targetBeep = new Audio('22540839_interface-alarm-03_by_umcsound_preview.mp3');

$("#top-left").delay(1000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1).animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"},100).animate({"color": "#323035"},100).animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"},100).animate({"color": "#323035"},100);
```

I would like the beep when it animates from `#FFFFFF` to `#323035`. I tried putting `targetBeep.play();` in the animation code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you're using at least jQuery v1.8, you can use the `start` or `complete` options in [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) (depending on exactly *when* you want the sound to play)

```js
$("#top-left")
  .delay(1000)
  .animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1)
  .animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"}, {
    duration: 100,
    start: () => {
      targetBeep.play()
    }
  })
  .animate({"color": "#323035"}, 100)
  .animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"}, 100)
  .animate({"color": "#323035"}, 100);
```